# Filtering realm on pivot table relationship

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, realm

Using realm I have setup 2 objects: `User` and `Question`.

Each User answers a Question, this is stored in a third object like so:

```
class Answer : Object {
    dynamic var user: User?
    dynamic var question: Question?
    dynamic var answerText = ""
}
```

What I need to do, is given a user object and a question object, get the related Answer object. In semi-SQL pseudo-code something like:

```
SELECT FROM Answers WHERE user = User and question = Question
```

**So...How do I achieve this?**

---

Bonus points if there is a way of not having to fetch the question object and instead use the primary key of that object (i have the user object, but only a question id, so i have to resolve the question object first), so something like:

```
SELECT FROM Answers WHERE user = User and question.id = Question.id
```

Also because realm doesn't load the entire object into memory until you need it, I don't think it's capable of that.

*Note: I've simplified by problem a little. There is a good reason I have the no primary answer id, so please don't tell me to add one.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to change your `User` model to include an inverse relationship with `Answer`. This will automatically include all answers where `user` equals the current user.

Then you will need to query the users, access their `answers` property and filter that based on the questions.

I have created these skeleton classes so that I can test the query, I know that your `User` and `Question` class might be different, so change the primaryKey and question filter to suit your exact class definition.

```
class User: Object {
    let answers = LinkingObjects(fromType: Answer.self, property: "user")
    dynamic var userName = ""
    override class func primaryKey()->String {
        return "userName"
    }
}

class Answer : Object {
    dynamic var user: User?
    dynamic var question: Question?
    dynamic var answerText = ""
}

class Question: Object {
    dynamic var title = ""
}

let questionId = ""
let questions = realm.object(ofType: User.self, forPrimaryKey: "userName")?.answers.filter("question.id = %@",questionId)
```

Comment: Thanks Dávid, I wasn't aware I could filter on related properties such as `user.id` so easily!, your answer led me to create a test app and I found I can do `realm.objects(Answer.self).filter("user.id = %@ AND question.id = %@", 1, 7)`. Thanks for your help